# SQL Select Help - Subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select the students who do not have a score for assignment 11, and return their names. Here are my tables & attempted solution.. each select works separately but not together.

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    Student_ID INT,
    Student_Name VARCHAR(10)
    )
INSERT INTO Student (Student_ID, Student_Name) VALUES (1,'Alex'),(2, 'Brett1'),(3,'Cora'),(4,'David'),(5,'Eleanor'),(6,'Brett2')

CREATE TABLE Grades(
    Student_ID INT,
    Assignment_ID INT,
    Grade INT
    )
INSERT INTO Grades (Student_ID, Assignment_ID, Grade) VALUES (1,10,90),(2,10,85),(3,10,75),(4,10,74),(1,11,80),(2,11,81),(4,11,88),(6,11,86),(2,12,84)`

SELECT *
    FROM Student s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Grades g on s.Student_ID=g.Student_ID
    WHERE g.Student_ID NOT IN(
    SELECT * FROM Grades g
    WHERE g.Assignment_ID = 11
    )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is a real joy to see a new person post a great question. While this has probably been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times you took the effort to post the tables, sample data and desired output. Well done!!!

Comment: Always welcome to be here, thanks to you and everyone else for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery here.

```
select *
from Student s
where not exists
(
    select *
    from Grades g
    where g.Student_ID = s.Student_ID
        AND g.Assignment_ID = 11
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were alomst there:

```
SELECT Student_ID 
FROM Student s
WHERE g.Student_ID NOT IN(
                           SELECT Student_ID FROM Grades g
                           WHERE g.Assignment_ID = 11 
                             AND Student_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Does not compile, `WHERE g.Student_ID NOT IN(` should read `WHERE Student_ID NOT IN(` and also he asked for the student names, not ID's.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Student_Name FROM Student AS s
LEFT JOIN Grades AS g
ON s.Student_ID = g.Student_ID AND g.Assignment_ID = 11
WHERE g.Grade IS NULL
```

[image]

**Note that if these were very large tables** there would be a small performance hit with the above compared to @SeanLange answer which might execute a tiny bit faster if all indices are properly set on each very large tables:

```
SELECT Student_Name FROM Student s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM Grades g
    WHERE g.Student_ID = s.Student_ID AND g.Assignment_ID = 11
)
```

Comment: Trying to isolate student names omitted from assignment 11, thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @that-ben you might consider changing your profile picture before you get banned.

Comment: @that-ben Don't beg for your answers to be accepted please, it's bad behaviour. Also, be careful when answering, this question is using SQL Server, not MySQL as you are showing.

Comment: @DavidG I was the only one with a working solution when I posted this.  Also, out of curiosity, what did I put in here that does not work with straight SQL?

Comment: It doesn't matter if your solution is working or not, begging for an accept is just bad behaviour. And your solution probably works with either server, but it may not have done, I'm just suggesting your take more care. The screenshot of MySQL could be very confusing to many users.

Comment: @DavidG So are you suggesting I remove my picture then? What are YOU begging for here?

Comment: I am not begging for anything. I was trying to be helpful and suggest that using a profile picture with bad language is not going to work well for you. I don't actually care one way or the other.

Comment: I'm asking you to be careful. The point of SO is to provide clear and concise answers that help everyone. Remove the images if you want, it's up to you, but if you start getting downvotes, that may be the reason why.

Comment: @SeanLange I was replying to DavidG but thanks for the suggestion.  I've been fine for over a year, but I'll change it if it's causing trouble ^.^;

Comment: Heh like I said I don't care. You would have to try a lot harder than that to offend me. :)

Comment: @DavidG The picture I thought was representative of the SQL query actually performing and it's clearly showing the result the OP was asking for.  It's not meant to promote MySQL or the use of phpMyAdmin or anything else but to, ironically, provide a clearer and concise answer... I cannot change the way people interpret things unfortunately but I thought it was a nice addition to my SQL query, don't you think?

Comment: I personally don't mind either way. However, what does it really add to your answer? The key bit is the SQL which is there, showing results doesn't prove anything - it's not something I would add to my answers as a general rule.

Comment: @DavidG It adds in it shows the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like:

```
;with cte (stId,asgId) as
(
   select s.Student_ID as stId ,g.Assignment_Id as asgId
   from Student s
   inner join Grades g on s.Student_Id = g.Student_ID
   where g.Assignment_Id = 11
)
select distinct Student_Name
from Student s
where s.Student_ID not in (select stId from cte)
```

Comment: Hey Eray, thanks for the response. That returns over names who have assignments 10 and 12 also, I'm looking for solely names that do not have assignment 11. Thank though! I tried the same thing :)

Comment: Not good, Alex, Brett1 and David are popping up but they DO have a score in assignment 11, please read OP's question carefully again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I understood the question incorrectly, fixed my answer.

Comment: We all did initially!

Answer (score 0):

I like Sean Lange's answer, but you could also use a sub-query and LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s.student_name
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT student_id
 FROM grades
 WHERE assignment_id = 11) sub
ON s.student_id = sub.student_id
WHERE sub.student_id IS NULL
```